# »Wir sind kurz davor, Artikel 7 auszulösen«

Tags: meaning-in-context

Ich zitiere aus einem [Artikel der österreichischen Tageszeitung *Die Presse*](http://diepresse.com/home/ausland/aussenpolitik/5254582/EUKommission-droht-Polen-mit-Entzug-des-Stimmrechtes), die eigentlich einen sehr guten Ruf hat:

> Die EU-Kommission hat am Mittwoch weitere Vertragsverletzungsverfahren gegen Polen wegen der "systematischen Bedrohung der Rechtsstaatlichkeit" angekündigt. Eine Entscheidung sei zwar noch nicht gefallen, doch dürfte dies nächste Woche der Fall sein. Die "Bedrohung der Rechtsstaatlichkeit hat sich deutlich verschärft" und: "**Wir sind kurz davor, Artikel 7 auszulösen**".

Auch in den Nachrichtensendungen des ORF wird die Formulierung »**den Artikel 7 auslösen**« verwendet. Auch »**den Artikel 7 aktivieren**« kann man hören.

Ist ein Artikel tatsächlich etwas, das man auslösen oder aktivieren kann? Sollte man nicht eher schreiben:

> »Wir sind kurz davor, Artikel 7 ***anzuwenden***«.

Frans Timmermans (EU-Kommissar für Bessere Rechtssetzung) hat wörtlich gesagt: *"Given the latest developments, we are coming very close to **triggering** Article 7."* Ich weiß aber nicht, ob das korrektes Englisch ist oder nicht.

Aber unabhängig davon, ob das Original gutes oder schlechtes Englisch ist: Kann man *to trigger* in diesem Fall wirklich mit *auslösen* übersetzen? Ist die Variante *aktivieren* legitim?

Comment: *to trigger* ist eigentlich **immer** *auslösen*. *Anwenden* kann hier wohl nicht gebraucht werden, weil der fragliche Artikel https://dejure.org/gesetze/EU/7.html nicht direkt durch die Vertragsstaaten umzusetzen ist. Die EU muss auf Antrag handeln, also passt *auslösen*. *Beantragen* wäre wohl besser.

Comment: In Artikel 7 ist von keinen Anträgen die Rede, sondern von Feststellungen und vom Entzug von Rechten. In Artikel 7 steht (gekürzt): *»Auf [...] Vorschlag [...] der Europäischen Kommission kann der Rat [...] feststellen, dass die eindeutige Gefahr einer schwerwiegenden Verletzung der [...] Werte durch einen Mitgliedstaat besteht. Wurde die Feststellung [...] getroffen, so kann der Rat […] beschließen, bestimmte Rechte auszusetzen.«* Ich meine daher, dass *anwenden* in diesem Fall bedeuten würde, dass die Kommission eine Feststellung macht, die dem Rat einen weiteren Schritt ermöglichen könnte.

Comment: "Auf begründeten Vorschlag" ist ein Antrag. Was sollte ein "begründeter Vorschlag" denn anderes sein?

Comment: @Janka: Ich denke, das verschiebt Huberts Frage lediglich in die Richtung, ob es nicht "die Anwendung von Artikel 7 auslösen" hätte heißen müssen.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: So sehe ich das auch. Allein stilistisch finde ich _eine Anwendung auslösen_ nicht sehr schön. Besser fände ich, einfach _anwenden_ zu sagen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Nein, das ist genau aus dem von Janka genannten Grund ein Unterschied, da das Subjekt die Anwendung nicht selber durchführt, sondern sie nur verursacht.

Comment: Ja okay, technisch ist der Rat das ausführende Organ.

Comment: Das Problem für den Zeitungsschreiber ist hier - wie man an der Diskussion in den Kommentaren sieht -, eine Balance zu finden zwischen der die komplizierte Akteursstruktur wiedergebenden Präzision (*die Anwendung von Paragraph 7 anzustoßen*) und einer dem Zeitungsleser zumutbaren Kompaktheit des Ausdrucks (*Artikel 7 anwenden/auslösen/aktivieren*). *Aktivieren* finde ich dabei noch die am wenigsten akzeptable Kurzform.

Comment: Oh, hier ist allerdings noch ein anderes Problem mit diesem Satz *Wir sind kurz davor, Artikel 7 auszulösen". In traditionellem gutem Deutsch würde man eher sagen "Wir **stehen** kurz davor, Artikel 7 xxxxx".

Comment: Das ist ja schon im Original neumodische Sprache. Vor 100 Jahren war *trigger* noch kein Verb!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beim *Auslösen* oder *Aktivieren* eines Artikels handelt es sich um die wörtliche Übersetzung zweier Metaphern aus dem Englischen. Im Englischen werden diese Metaphern so häufig verwendet, dass sie schon fast nicht mehr als solche empfunden werden. Im Deutschen ist das noch nicht der Fall. Daher ist die wörtliche Übersetzung grundsätzlich möglich, aber nicht immer sinnvoll.

In der ersten Metapher wird Artikel 7 EU-Vertrag als ein Mechanismus angesehen, den man 'auslösen' kann. Dieser Vergleich eines Artikels mit einem Mechanismus wird immer wieder sogar explizit gezogen. (Zwangsläufig auch im Deutschen, denn das *kann* man ja gar nicht anders übersetzen.)  Deshalb scheint mir die wörtliche Übersetzung in diesem Fall völlig unproblematisch. Dadurch, dass es gute Gründe gibt, sich Artikel 7 sogar als eine Bombe oder Kanone vorzustellen und die englische Wortwahl *trigger* möglicherweise darauf anspielt, scheint es mir in diesem Fall auch definitiv die beste Übersetzung zu sein, da auch die (potenzielle) Anspielung im Deutschen vorhanden ist.

Nach denselben Überlegungen ist auch die Übersetzung von *activate* als *aktivieren* in diesem Kontext korrekt, wenn auch nicht ganz so zwingend.

Die maßvolle wörtliche Übersetzung von Metaphern aus anderen Sprachen ist einer der Mechanismen, die eine Sprache auf lange Sicht bereichern. Wenn man beispielsweise *apply / activate / trigger* in diesem Kontext alle gleichermaßen mit *anwenden* übersetzt, gehen feine Nuancen unter. Falsch wäre es aber nicht - solange die Nuancen nicht z.B. im selben Text explizit gemacht werden. Wenn man z.B. wüsste, dass im ursprünglichen Text *keine* Anspielung auf die Zündung einer Bombe beabsichtigt war, wäre das evt. sogar die bessere Übersetzung, weil die Metapher ja im Deutschen noch nicht so abgegriffen ist.

PS: Diese griffigen Metaphern scheinen relativ neu zu sein. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass die erste *(trigger/auslösen)* ursprünglich in der EU-Bürokratie aufgekommen ist. Den Durchbruch ins allgemeine Bewusstsein hat sie wahrscheinlich kurz nach dem Brexit-Referendum genommen. Google setzt "trigger article" nämlich fast ausnahmslos mit "50" fort, was die Nummer des EU-Ausstiegs-Artikels ist. Die andere Metapher *(activate/aktivieren)* scheint mir ebenfalls relativ jung, aber schon etwas etablierter auch in einem UN-Kontext. So wurde z.B. in einer Arbeit von 1993 davon gesprochen, wegen der Sowjetunion Artikel 43 der UN-Charta zu aktivieren.

Beide Metaphern scheinen hauptsächlich in Verbindung mit 'explosiven' Vertragsartikeln verwendet zu werden. Ich vermute deshalb, dass *activate* die zensierte Version von früher nur umgangssprachlich verwendetem *trigger* ist. Eine noch drastischere deutsche *Übersetzung* wäre *zünden*. Das entsprechende englische Verb *light* lässt sich nicht gut metaphorisch verwenden, weshalb *zünden* in manchen Fällen durchaus angebracht wäre. (Drastischstes deutsches Verb für drastischstes englisches Verb.)

PPS: Als Mathematiker bin ich daran gewöhnt, mit sprachlichen Tricks wie Metaphern arbeiten zu müssen, um komplizierte und differenzierte Sachverhalte kurz, prägnant, anschaulich und dennoch präzise beschreiben zu können. An diesem Beispiel sehe ich, dass es Juristen genauso geht.

Comment: *Die maßvolle wörtliche Übersetzung von Metaphern aus anderen Sprachen ist einer der Mechanismen, die eine Sprache auf lange Sicht bereichern.* Ja - um solchen Unsinn wie "macht Sinn"...

Comment: "Sinn machen" ist nur dann Unsinn, wenn man will, dass es Unsinn ist, weil man ein gestörtes Verhältnis zum Englischen hat und keine richtigen Argumente findet. Als noch nicht das Englische sondern das Französische dominant war, waren die Leute, die das Deutsche von romanischen Einflüssen reinigen wollten, wenigstens noch mit Lehnübersetzungen wien "Stelldichein" (für "Rendezvous") zufrieden. Bis auf die ganz extremen - und teils scherzhaften - Vorschläge wie "Gesichtserker" für das ursprl. lateinische "Nase" natürlich.

Comment: Ih sehe keine Argumente, warum "Sinn machen" einen Sinn ergeben sollte und ich habe keinerlei gestörtes Verhältnis zum Englischen, ich spreche es sogar täglich. Es ist nunmal so, dass man im Deutschen keinen Sinn machen kann, sondern nur Unsinn.

Comment: "Sinn machen" ist ursprl. eine ganz normale Metapher, wie sie in guter Prosa ständig vorkommt. Wenn ein Vorschlag Sinn macht, kann man sich z.B. vorstellen, dass er an einem Tisch sitzt und sich mit Schere, Klebstoff und Papier einen Sinn bastelt. Im Gegensatz zu Freistil-Metaphern ist diese hier nur schon so stark abgegriffen, dass man sie als solche kaum mehr wahrnimmt - so stark wie z.B. "sich den Wanst vollhauen" und stärker als z.B. "bei jemandem gutes Wetter machen" oder "eine gute Klinge schlagen". Gerade das beweist, dass sie längst auch im Deutschen eine idiomatische Wendung ist.

Answer (score 2):

Die Frage hat zwei Ebenen:

1) Was ist ein angemessener Ausdruck dafür, wenn die zuständigen Institutionen (jede mit den ihr eigenen Kompetenzen) die von Artikel 7 vorgesehenen Maßnahmen umzusetzen beginnen.

2) Wenn der EU-Kommissar für dieses - erkennbarerweise recht komplexe - System von Schritten auf Englisch kurz und einfach sagt *to trigger Article 7*, und dies - nehmen wir einmal an - auch auf English nicht wirklich korrekt (aber eben schön kurz) ist, sollte man dann die Worte des Kommissars möglichst originalgetreu übersetzen, oder sollte man korrigierend eingreifen und auf Deutsch einen präziseren Ausdruck wählen als der Kommmisar auf Englisch?

Ich würde in diesem Fall dazu tendieren, eher dicht am englischen Originaltext zu bleiben, einfach mit der (faulen?) Begründung, dass der Kommissar das nun mal so gesagt hat. Also: Ja, "Artikel 7 auslösen" geht.

Anders steht es, wenn ich selbst mich zur Ingangsetzung der Prozedur nach Artikel 7 äußern sollte. Vielleicht würde ich in der Tat von

> die Prozedur nach Artikel 7 in Gang setzen

sprechen. (Bis ich des umständlichen Ausdrucks müde bin und dann doch auf

> Artikel 7 auslösen

einschwenke.)

---

PS: Ich kann natürlich folgenden Kompromiss machen: Ich kann schreiben

> Der Kommissar sagte, die EU-Kommission sei kurz davor "Artikel 7 auszulösen".

Mit den Gänsefüßchen zeige ich an, dass der Kommissar das zwar so gesagt hat, dass ich mich von der Formulierung aber distanziere z.B. weil ich weiß, dass sie verwaltungstechnisch unpräzise ist.

Aktueller Fall aus der Medienwirklichkeit 2017: Aus dem E-Mail, mit dem ein gewisser Rob Goldstone im Wahlkampf 2016 einem gewissen Donald Trump junior die Vermittlung nützlicher Kontakte nach Russland angeboten hat, wird derzeit sehr häufig zitiert mit

> that “the Crown prosecutor of Russia" had met with Aras Agalarov and offered to provide some official documents that might be useful for the Trump campaign

wobei das Problem ist, dass es einen solchen *Crown prosecutor of Russia*  nicht gibt. Nun kann man aber auch nicht einfach jenen obersten Staatsanwalt hineinschreiben, der vermutlich damit gemeint war (nämlich den *Prosecutor-general of the Russian Federation*), denn man weiß ja nicht, ob Rob Goldstone wirklich diesen meinte, und vor allem ginge ein buntes Stück aus dieser absurden Geschichte verloren. Also ist die Lösung, die Worte so zu nehmen, wie sie sind, und mit Gänsefüßchen zu signalisieren, dass daran aber etwas faul ist.

Answer (score 1):

Einen Artikel kann man weder "auslösen" noch "triggern" - Es handelt sich hier wohl sowohl im Englischen als auch im Deutschen um eine (mMn tolerierbare) Verkürzung des Satzes

> wir sind kurz davor, ein Vertragsverletzungsverfahren nach Artikel 7 auszulösen

Es wird aber durch den Kontext deutlich klar, was gemeint ist.

> Wir sind kurz davor, Artikel 7 anzuwenden

ist nicht exakt dasselbe und im Prinzip auch falsch, wenn nicht sogar "noch falscher". Die Europäische Kommission kann  nämlich "Artikel 7" gar nicht anwenden, das kann nur der Europäische Rat. Die Kommission kann den Rat aber *veranlassen*, das zu tun - was eben mit "trigger" gemeint ist.

Ganz richtig wäre also möglicherweise,

> wir sind kurz davor, den Europäischen Rat zu veranlassen, ein Vertragsverletzungsverfahren nach Artikel 7 einzuleiten

... und das ist natürlich schon wesentlich länger.

*aktivieren* paßt auch nicht besonders gut - Artikel 7 ist Bestandteil des EU-Vetrags, und der wurde für jeden Mitliedsstaat mit der Unterschrift "aktiv" und ist es seither immer gewesen.